# How to add a radio button in lwc datatable?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, checkbox, radio-button

I am trying to add a radio button at the end of a datatable row, so basically I need two selection option, one is the checkbox given by default which is shown at the very front of each row, and a radio button at the last of the row, I can insert a button but changing the column attribute type to 'radio' is not working for me.

> {type: "radio", initialWidth: 50, typeAttributes: {
> label: '',
> value: '' }}

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`radio` is not a supported data type. You would need to make a custom data type, as written in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation) under "Creating Custom Data Types".

Answer (score 5):

Using: <lightning-dattable **max-row-selection="1"**>
According to the [lwc datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/specification) documentation: Radio buttons are used when maxRowSelection is 1.

Comment: I needed both checkbox and radio, so extending the Datatable class and creating a custom radio button column is the right approach.